# How to get all maximum repeated items in a python list of strings?

Tags: python

I have python list. I want to get all the items that are repeated maximum in it. The example list below has two items repeated twice and I want to get both. Applying max() to list, I could get only one item (either the first or last occurrence) that is repeated maximum.

```
cool = ['similar', 'neutral', 'contradict', 'similar', 'neutral']    
print(max(cool, key=cool.count))
```

I tried Counter() and still can only return one maximum item from list. How to get both the items repeated maximum from a python list?

Comment: Store `max_count = max(counter.values())` and return `[k for k, v in counter.items() if v == max_count]`.

Comment: Agree with @hilberts_drinking_problem, that seems to be the most efficient solution (creating a Counter has `O(n)` complexity, finding the max value has `O(p)` complexity (p < n) and creating the list has `O(p)` complexity too)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Counter` class,

```
from collections import Counter

cool = ['similar', 'neutral', 'contradict', 'similar', 'neutral'] 

result = []
counter = Counter(cool)
max_value = counter.most_common(1)[0][1]

for key, value in dict(counter).items():
    if(value == max_value):
        result.append(key)
        
print(result)
```